# laravel email not send from localhost

Tags: laravel, authentication

i am using xampp (windows) with latest php version and laravel 5.4. here is my .env settings

```
MAIL_DRIVER = smtp 
MAIL_HOST = smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_USERNAME = myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD = mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls
```

and the controller code

```
use Mail;
Mail::send('mail.login-verificatio', $data, function($message) use($email_to) 
{
$message->to($email_to, '')->subject
    ('Login Security Number');
$message->from('myemail@gmail.com','xxxxxxxxxxx');
 });
```

but i found the following error

```
ErrorException
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

THanks

Comment: did allow access for localhost in the email setup for gmail?

Answer (score -1):

Please try to follow below methods:

1) You can use below code in your config/mail.php file.

```
'stream' => [
'ssl' => [
    'allow_self_signed' => true,
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
  ],
],
```

2) Try to remove TLS in config/mail.php file.

```
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''), //'tls')
```